# How to create custom web.config in ASP.Net MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, publish

Only having debug and release web.config files is not enough for our deployment process. We use the standard `Web.config` for local development, `Web.Debug.config` for the shared development environment, and `Web.Release.config` for staging and production environments.

Now we would like to have a distinct configuration for staging and production environments.
Is it possible to create a new configuration profile 'staging', have the associated web.staging.config, and tell the build process to use the transformations it defines when we select the appropriate publish profile?

Comment: @Raj, I'm not trying to add a new config file, but a new config transform for the one I have.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok I got it. You need to go to the solution's properties > `Configuration` > `Configuration Manager`. Open the `Active solution configuration` dropdown > `New`, to create a new configuration scheme. Leave the `Create new project configurations` checked.

Then right-click the web.config file and click `Add Config Transform`. Finally, you can edit the publish profiles to use the new configuration.

Comment: +1 caught be out not adding the new configs in the config manager first. Kept wondering why it just kept adding a new web config instead of a nested one!